# Get json user from json tweet

Tags: java, twitter4j

I have a tweet that I had stored in a file. I want to extract the user as a json object and store it in a different file. The following results in `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Apparently jsonStoreEnabled is not set to true.`

```
String jsonStatus; //Content read from a file
Status status = TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(jsonStatus); //no problem here
String jsonUser = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status.getUser()); //Exception
```

How can I set `jsonStoreEnabled` to `true`? Or, is there another way of doing it? I don't have to stick with `Twitter4j` to create `jsonUser`. I tried `json-simple`, but the resulting String is not parsable with Twitter4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `org.json` package was helpful in this case:

```
public static String extractUser(String rawJSON) {
    return new org.json.JSONObject(rawJSON).get("user").toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

TwitterObjectFactory has a variable called registeredAtleastOnce that if false you will get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Apparently jsonStoreEnabled is not set to true.`. You can see this page
[TwitterObjectFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-core/4.0.1/twitter4j/TwitterObjectFactory.java#TwitterObjectFactory.0registeredAtleastOnce)
So, if you don't want that error you will have to make once call to the Twitter API, for example for the first line of your file

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
             cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
             .setOAuthConsumerKey(Ckey)
             .setOAuthConsumerSecret(CkeySecret)
             .setOAuthAccessToken(AToken))
             .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(AtokenSecret)
             .setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
String jsonStatus; //Content read from a file
Status status = TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(jsonStatus); //your status
User u2 = t.showUser(status.getUser().getScreenName()); // you use the twitter object once
String jsonUser = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status.getUser()); //now you won't get the error
System.out.print(jsonUser); //your happy json
```

In that way you wouldn't get that error

Comment: The json object is read from a file, not streamed from Twitter.

Comment: Twitter4j has a paramater in the TwitterObjectFactory called "registeredAtleastOnce", if it's False you'll get "Apparently jsonStoreEnabled is not set to true.", so you have to use at least once you configuration builder

Comment: This parameter is set to true when the tweets are retrieved from the API, and setJSONStoreEnabled is set to true. The former condition does not apply to my question.